# Does "da" mean "by" or "from" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, prepositions

I have a question about how to interpret the word *da* in a context where it seems like it could mean either *by* or *from*. Consider this example sentence:

> Da chi sono stati comprati questi guanti?

It seems to me like both of the following translations are possible:

> *By* whom were these gloves bought? (i.e., who is the buyer?)
>
> *From* whom were these gloves bought? (i.e., who is the seller?)

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: I got the example sentence from page 233 (Chapter 17, Exercise A) of the book "L'italiano secondo il metodo natura".

Comment: It can mean both, depending on the context. But probably the second interpretation would be expressed with *Dove sono stati comprati?*

Comment: @egreg: What about converting your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no unique correct interpretation: it could mean both and only the context can suggest the intended meaning.

The preposition *da* is used with personal nouns or pronouns to mean motion to or state in: *vado dal salumiere* or *sono dal dentista*. By extension, we can use it also for *ho comprato i guanti da Xyz*. The English translation for such *da* would be *at Xyz’s*.

You're also right in thinking that *da* is the main proposition for denoting the agent in a passive form.

Thus the example is indeed ambiguous, because there is no grammatical way to distinguish between the two meanings. It's a bit artificial, though.

In the *by* meaning, an active form *Chi ha comprato questi guanti?* would be preferred. In the *at*/*from* meaning I'd personally ask *Dove sono stati comprati questi guanti?*